# Conditional formatting based on changes in text between two Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have two Google sheets that have exactly the same columns and rows except Sheet 1 gets updated and Sheet 2 does not. I would like to have the cells in the updated Sheet 1 be conditionally formatted based on the cells in Sheet 2. Both sheets are using text/strings rather than numbers.

Example:

Sheet 1/cell A1: text = "Closed"

Sheet 2/cell A1: text = "Opened"

Sheet 1/cell A1 gets conditionally formatted as RED when Sheet 1/cell A1 is both

a) different from Sheet 2/cell A1 and

b) contains the word "Closed" as opposed to "Open."

Would also like to know if it's possible to do this on cells that contain multiple words!

Have been looking in REGEXMATCH but can't seem to get it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jZKoFDrizYzI0gsOexmWLawi9cyU2z6D_Dq5YslT8c0/edit?usp=sharing example sheet linked here! Thank you for any and all help!!!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT("Sheet2!C:C"), "Closed|Banned")
```

Comment: This worked but also seems to conditionally format all of the cells regardless of if the cell content has changed from Closed to Banned between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Perhaps I'm cell referencing incorrectly? If you're able, can you look at the link again and let me know your thoughts?